# Sending data from Form2 to Form1 once the user inputs the required things in some text boxes in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I am making a program for a friend and I need it to be were when she types in a number corresponding to the form that opens when she hits 'go' that form will open. I have that part done. The issue I have is when the new form opens I have a series of text boxes that she needs to input data into like '1 can of fresh beans' and some other stuff in some other text boxes on that form. Now when she is done typing in all the required things she will hit a submit button that will then format the code accordingly to the way I have it set to like this

```
richTextBox1.Text += "This is some text that I type before" + AmntItemsTxtBox + " and this is some other stuff";
```

So that is what I kind of want to happen. Now I know I may have confused some people but what I ran into as an issue is how do I take what she typed in form 2 and send it to the richtextbox in form 1 when she hits the button so she can copy and paste it into something else later on. I know my code seems a bit "new" but I am just starting out with C# and wanting to learn more. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done it in my sample project. It may help you.

Form 1:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.txtmessagechanged += new EventHandler(txt_messagechanged);
        frm2.ShowDialog(this);
    }


private void txt_messagechanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtMessage.Text = (string)sender;
        }
```

Form 2 :

```
 public EventHandler txtmessagechanged { get; set; }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            string a = textBox1.Text;
            if (txtmessagechanged != null)
                txtmessagechanged(a, null);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fill some data in textbox");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
```

Image of form 1 (on button click event it open form 2):

[image]

Input in form 2 (put some value in text box) :

[image]

Get text in form 1 on form 2 close event.

[image]

**You can modify it according to your needs.**

Answer (score 0):

Form 1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
        frm2.Show();
    }
```

From 2

```
public Form2(string msg)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Text = msg;
    }
```

That is how you pass data (or at least one way of doing it). Then you can do whatever you want with it and format it however you like.

Comment: OP asked for "take what she typed in form 2 and send it to form 1" your answer looks like Form1 --> Form2